Tooltip Blinking Issue on Hover over Skill Bubble (React & d3)
I'm encountering an issue with tooltips on my website where they keep blinking when hovering over skill bubbles. I've implemented the tooltips at a fixed location, but whenever there's a bubble on that location and I hover over it, the tooltip starts blinking until I remove my cursor from the bubble. I've tried adjusting the z-index to move the tooltip behind the bubble, but it doesn't seem to work. I suspect this might be due to using D3, which manipulates the DOM continuously.
Image of the page with bubble and tooltip (on hover)
Help me identify the root cause of this issue and suggest a fix? Additionally, here are some additional details:
Video of the issue occurring:   video 
URL of my portfolio where you can generate the issue:   url
Source code link on GitHub:    code
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
PS: Due to the size of the code, it cannot be displayed in a single code snippet. However, you can find the complete code in the provided GitHub repository link for further reference.

Maybe css below solve your problem, try this on your words:
pointer-events: none;


Thank you for the suggestion. I've tried implementing the CSS property "pointer-events: none;", but unfortunately, it disables the tooltip functionality altogether. Since the tooltip is triggered on mouseover, disabling pointer events will prevent it from appearing. I'm still exploring other solutions to address the blinking issue without compromising the tooltip functionality. code:296

You need to put the pointer-events: none; on your tooltip div, not the circles.  You should probably also apply it to the text within each circle.
